# javascript set key in map instead of variable name

Tags: javascript

why in this code, `a` is interpreted as real key name, not value hidden under `a` variable?

```js
function myfunc(a,b)
{
return {a:b};
}

var c = myfunc("key","value");
console.log(c);
```

This code print:

```
{
  a: "value"
}
```

not:

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

How to modify this code, to use value under `a` as key name?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `{}.a` means property `a` of the object and doesn't refer to any variables you have.
In order to use some variable as a key, you need to use `[a]` instead. You may read more on this topic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).

```
function myfunc(a,b)
{
  return {[a]:b}; // note I added [ ]
}
```

Comment: hah, I don't know why, but working, Thank You!

Comment: Yes, I want do it, but "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes"
PS: thank you for fast response ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [bracket notation] for a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

```js
function myfunc(a, b) {
  return {
    [a]: b
  };
}

var c = myfunc("key", "value");
console.log(c);
```